# HtmlUnit + Webclient.getPage throws

Tags: java, htmlunit, htmlunit-driver

I am trying to access a URL (`admin.do`) directly after logging into the application and the URL is a restricted page. However, when I run the scenario on browser, I am able to see the page getting redirected to access denied page. However, when I run the same with htmlunit, I see the following exception instead.

```
com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.FailingHttpStatusCodeException: 403 Forbidden for https://localhost:27216/app/admin.do
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.throwFailingHttpStatusCodeExceptionIfNecessary(WebClient.java:536)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.getPage(WebClient.java:331)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.getPage(WebClient.java:387)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.getPage(WebClient.java:372)
```

Any idea how to achieve this? Here is my code.

```
HtmlPage resp = null;
WebClient webClient = getWebClient();
HtmlPage page = (HtmlPage) webClient.getPage(url);
```

Comment: Check the headers. It maybe that the browser captured the cookies whereas htmlunit ignore it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Got it working. The exception is thrown and hence it doesn't allow the page to follow the redirect. I set the property `throwExceptionOnFailingStatusCode` on the `WebClient` to `false`, so that the the exception is ignored.

```
HtmlPage resp = null;
WebClient webClient = getWebClient();
webClient.setThrowExceptionOnFailingStatusCode(false);
HtmlPage page = (HtmlPage) webClient.getPage(url);
```